# How to know if the row contains "values" in either of the lists?

Tags: r

```
a<- c("H","W")
b<- c("Y","S","I")

df1 <- t(data.frame(c("Y","S","I","F","C","T","V")))
df2 <- t(data.frame(c("Y","S","I","Y","Y","Y","Y")))
df3 <- t(data.frame(c("H","H","W")))
```

'''
How to have a function, such that when I apply it, df1 will appear FALSE because it does not contain only those elements in "a" or "b", while df2 and df3 will appear TRUE because df2 contained elements in "b" and df3 contain elements in "a"?

Thank you!

Comment: df1 contains all the elements of b in the same way that df2 does. Can you check your question? Also you code has errors, because the parentheses don't close on the dfs

Comment: Hi, because df1 contains elements outside a or b, so I would want to make it false. Sorry I don't understand on the parentheses don't close on the dfs..

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the unique values in the data frame column are the same as the values in one of both vectors. We have to sort the values before making the comparison to make sure they become identical:

```
a<- c("H","W")
b<- c("Y","S","I")

df1 <- data.frame(c("Y","S","I","F","C","T","V"))
df2 <- data.frame(c("Y","S","I","Y","Y","Y","Y"))
df3 <- data.frame(c("H","H","W"))

func <- function(df, vec1, vec2) {
  vec1 = sort(vec1)
  vec2 = sort(vec2)
  unique = sort(unique(df[,1]))
  identical(unique,vec1) | identical(unique,vec2)
}

> func(df1,a,b)
[1] FALSE
> func(df2,a,b)
[1] TRUE
> func(df3,a,b)
[1] TRUE
>
```

By the way, I removed the transpose from your example because there were no closing brackets.

Comment: if c<- c("Y","Y","Y") , then it is FALSE, which is not the true. May I know how to rectify?

Comment: What do you mean with c here? Is this a new data frame of a new vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all` and `%in%` to test if all elements of df1, df2 or df3 are either in `a` or `b`.

```
all(df1 %in% a | df1 %in% b)
#[1] FALSE
all(df2 %in% a | df2 %in% b)
#[1] TRUE
all(df3 %in% a | df3 %in% b)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or if `a` and `b` should be combined:

```
all(df1 %in% c(a,b))
```